# Why is my QML GroupBox not sizing properly within a layout?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make two group boxes appear next to each other so that each one occupies 50% of the window. However, it looks like the width of each GroupBox is somehow changed depending on the GroupBox title length.

If the GroupBox title is the same for both GroupBox's, it will be 50% of the window. If they are not the same, the GroupBox with the longer title will occupy more of the screen.

It doesn't make sense to me for this to happen, how can I fix it so the length of the title doesn't effect the size of the GroupBox in a layout?

Here's sample code to reproduce the issue...

**AppGroupBox.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

GroupBox {
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
    spacing:0
    label.x: 0
}
```

**AppRowLayout.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

RowLayout {
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
    spacing: 0
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true


    AppRowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        AppGroupBox {
            title: "Short Name"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        AppGroupBox {
            title: "Much Longer Name"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt will distribute the free space relative to the `Layout.preferredWidth` (or `implicitWidth` if that isn't defined). So, a group box with a longer title will get more space by default, as its `implicitWidth` is larger.

The solution is to use a fixed `preferredWidth` for all elements in the `RowLayout`:

```
GroupBox {
    ...
    Layout.preferredWidth: 50 // or any other fixed value.
    Layout.minimumWidth: implicitWidth // OPTIONAL: may be usefull on small screens to ensure the box is not made smaller than the title width
    ...
}
```

**Note on attached properties:**

`Layout.alignment` is an attached property available on the **children** of a `Layout` (`RowLayout`, `GridLayout` or `ColumnLayout`). Setting it directly inside a `RowLayout` object is useless (except when the `RowLayout` itself is a child of another `Layout` item.

Comment: It's odd that is needed, but it seems even setting a preferredWidth of 0 fixes it. Thanks!